# Permission in zabbix to access restricted files

Tags: permissions, zabbix

I'm trying to get the checksum of some files in my servers to monitor their changes. I cannot change there permissions because they're so important. I've heard that I can use ACL method for using
vfs.file.cksum[MyFile,sha256], But I don't know how to do that.
I have CentOS7 and Ubuntu20.04 and Zabbix 6. Now I get this error: "Cannot open file: [13] Permission denied".
here might be other ways I'm not thinking of, and it's my pleasure to use your advices.

Thank you.

Comment: You write "i can't change their permissions", so you can't monitor them, unless you run Zabbix as Administrator.

Comment: Thank you Iron, I mean I cannot change permissions with chmod ( -rw------- )... .

Comment: If the permissions are 600, you can't check it, unless as admin, as Iron mentioned. If you can have at least 660 and adding zabbix user to particular group (non-sudo), this is one way out.